# Phonegap build does not work

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

I have tried to build my app on Phonegap with plugin and got error for Android:

"Error - Some official plugins have to be updated if using PhoneGap >= 4.0.0. Please upgrade the version of any plugins that may include the following file: LocalNotification.java".

So i changed the source for plugin from:

```js
<plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification" source="pgb"/>
```

to:

```js
<plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification" source="npm" />
```

and now i get error for IOS build that says:

"Error - The following plugin, plugin version or a dependancy of this plugin is not on npm: de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification"

So when i use one source i have build for Android but don't have for IOS, and other source allowes me to build IOS but not Android. Also if i don't set the version, it should use the latest one, making my first error message unclear to me.

What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Double check the version of phonegap you maybe using.

If you are using the remote build process [here](https://build.phonegap.com/) and have an **old** version of phonegap running then your problem maybe that your plugins are configured for a local build not a remote one.

Basically, this:

```
<plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification" source="npm" />
```

is actually this:

```
<gap:plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification" source="npm" />
```

with older versions of phonegap. More info [here](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_plugins.md.html).

Your options maybe to upgrade to a newer version of phonegap or change the plugin declarations as I have shown above.

Comment: i solved the problem by adding:
<gap:plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification-ios9-fix" version="0.8.2" />

Comment: Glad you sorted it out ? Did you also have to change the `<plugin` to `<gap:plugin` as I suspected ?